# Why does my Java program hang when I call it from Perl?

Tags: perl

Inside a Perl script, I want to run a Java program that takes in 2 inputs, which will be passed by the command line.

So I do:

```
if (scalar @ARGV == 2)
{ print `java myProg $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`; } 
elsif (scalar @ARGV == 1) 
{ print `java myProg $ARGV[0]`; }
```

I works if I enter 2 args, but still hangs if I enter only 1 arg

How should I correct it?

BTW, the Java program works.

---

I changed my Perl script to:

```
print scalar @ARGV;
print `$ARGV[0]`;
print `$ARGV[1]`;
```

And if I run 'perl myPerl.pl abc def' in command line, it only prints 2. And not my two inputs. WHY!?

Comment: Does `java myProg var1 var2` work from the command line?

Comment: Also, give us some realistic examples of input for `var1` and `var2` so we can help you better.

Comment: Don't put "URGENT" in your question.  You can be assured that someone will look at the question and answer it quickly (the majority of questions get answers within hours, and some even within minutes).

Comment: A) This isn't a syntax problem.   B)  This isn't urgent

Comment: Actually I know what my probelm is, sometimes arg[2] will not be entered. so hwo can check if arg[2] is entered?

Comment: now that you changed the program you are missing the backticks.  Also the indentation is awful.  I don't have enough rep to fix it for you :(

Comment: I did not miss the backticks in my program, just fixed the my post. Problem still exists.

Comment: woah there!!!!  you do know that backticks are calling the string within them on the command line right.  If all you want to do is print them put them in quotations.  print "$ARGV[1]";

Comment: Ok. But what if i want to combine ARGV[1] and a command together?

Comment: my $command = join " ", "java", @ARGV;

Comment: No. still can't figure it out.

Comment: You gotta start giving me some feedback on what I was asking for.  For example, did you try the program I posted that just prints stuff?   did you try the program that runs the "cat" command instead of java"?  Did you look for the java program in your process list?

Comment: Does your Java program take input from the command line arguments (the `String[] args` in your `main` method) or does it expect input from the console (`System.in`) ?

Comment: Ok. This is weird.

If i do java MyProg arg1 on command line, it works.

if i do echo `java MyProg arg1` , it hangs.

Comment: The last two prints don't work very well because you are using back-ticks to execute a command that probably doesn't exist (abc, def).

Comment: 1) calm down.  2) run the programs in my answer below and see what happens.  3)  Figure out why the java program is hanging (waiting for standard in perhaps?)

Comment: NO, I TOLD YOU. THE JAVA PROGRAM WORKS FINE.

Your program below works fine in terms of printing out the arguments. But i want to embed those arguments as inputs to my java program.

Comment: Why don't you show us the Java program you are trying to run, some examples of arguments that you would pass to the Java and Perl programs, and any information about your environment that might be relevant (like if/how does `$CLASSPATH` get set, path to the Java interpreter, whether the command "java" is aliased to anything, etc.)

Comment: @Saobi, once again, Calm down, or people won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code sample is heading off the rails, but the first code sample looks correct, more-or-less. Let's have a look at the Java code, your environment, or anything else that can help us figure out why

```
{ print `java myProg $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`; }
```

works and

```
{ print `java myProg $ARGV[0]`; }
```

doesn't.

Comment: "off the rails".  I love it, I'm going to have to use that tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your latest question:

```
print scalar @ARGV;
print `$ARGV[0]`;
print `$ARGV[1]`;
```

The above code doesn't print the data you expect because you are using backticks with some random input data. Perl is trying to execute the shell commands "abc" and "def" (as per your example) and captures the output of running those commands, of which there isn't any. Try printing the values directly:

```
print scalar @ARGV;
print $ARGV[0], "\n";
print $ARGV[1], "\n";
```

Comment: Let's hope he really used "abc" and "def".

Answer (score 3):

***The java program is hanging***. Try it straight from the command line.

To check if there are enough args you can do:

```
 die "needs 2 args" unless (scalar @ARGV == 2);
```

Try this code to prove it is the java:

```
if (scalar @ARGV == 2)
{ 
    print `cat myProg $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`; 
} 
elsif (scalar @ARGV==1) 
{ 
    print `cat myProg $ARGV[0]`; 
}
```

If all you want to do is print the arguments:

```
if (scalar @ARGV == 2)
{ 
    print "arguments = [$ARGV[0]] [$ARGV[1]]\n"; 
} 
elsif (scalar @ARGV==1) 
{ 
    print "arguments = [$ARGV[0]]\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Can shorten to `unless @ARGV == 2;` - `scalar()` isn't necessary in scalar context.

Comment: No reason to shorten things.  Perl is already hard enough to understand.

Comment: I don't see how it's any easier to understand. A curious person is still going to ask what `scalar()` does, and you're still going to have to explain scalar/list context to them.

Comment: I have:

if (scalar @ARGV == 2){
print `java myProg $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`;
}
elsif (scalar @ARGV==1)
{
print `java myProg $ARGV[0]`;
}


I works if i enter 2 args, but still hangs if i enter only 1 arg.

Comment: I'm telling you.  THE JAVA PROGRAM IS HANGING!

Comment: Run the program, then do a "ps -ef | grep java" (if you are on *nix) otherwise open process explorer or task manager and look for the Java process.  After that, if you are still sure java isn't hanging let me know.

Comment: change the call from java to something else.  That will prove it is java.

Comment: May I be the first (oddly) to ask "What are you trying to accomplish?"

Comment: For now , let's just say i am tryign to write a perl program that prints out all my command line inputs.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do whatever you're trying to do at the start of your Java program?

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  Yes, it does seem odd that Java's not being called directly.  It's not like you can't do argument processing in Java, seeing as how arguments come into Java's main method as a String array.

Comment: He could be creating a command to run from the command line so you don't have to write "java " before the command.

Comment: @tster - There are undoubtedly much better ways to do that.

Comment: meh, not really.  I mean, you could do it with a shell script but is that really "better?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $BASE_COMMAND = 'java MyProgram';

die "Illegal argument count - must have one or two arguments."
    unless @ARGV == 1 or @ARGV == 2;

# Arrays interpolate into space separated strings (unless you change $" - see perlvar)
my $command = "$BASE_COMMAND @ARGV";

print "Running '$command'\n";
print `$command`;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `$#ARGV` to find the index of the last array element of `@ARGV`.  Add 1 to that and you can get the arg count.

```
my $argCount = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($argCount == 1)
{
    die "Please enter 2 arguments!\n";
}
```

Comment: @tster: Then $#ARGV should be undef.

Comment: That was just a sample showing how to use $#array; it is not meant to be the final production code to check the arguments.

Comment: Just evaluate @ARGV in scalar context.  No need to mess around with $#ARGV.  `my $argCount = @ARGV;`